# Выборка даты без времени

Tags: sql, html, php, mysql

Подскажите запрос на выборку только даты из БД. Имеется строка в таблице формата TIMESTAMP 0000-0-0 00:00:00 , так вот как сделать что бы на экран выводилась только дата а не дата со временем ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `date_field` , '%d %M %Y' ) AS `date_format` FROM `table_name`
```

Comment: А как сделать чтоб %M — на русском выводило?)

Comment: @junior-web-dev, запрос перед этим сделайте: `SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';`

Answer (score 1):

Функция [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

> SELECT DATE(`some_field` ) FROM `some_table`

Больше [функций](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) - красивых и разных.

Answer (score 0):

В конце выбранного названия колонки дописать ::date, если я правильно вас понял.

Comment: Вот пример, чтоб было более понятно.
select shipments.ship_date::date,customer_id,publication, type from shipments, editions, stock ORDER BY publication;

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста результат вашего запроса на каком-то sql fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

вот [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=621036) смотрите, думаю, найдете, что искали